# path to WMI source code in perl CPAN (in command prompt)

Tags: windows, perl, cpan

while Try to install Net::WMIClient. In command prompt i receive a request 
"Enter the path to the WMI source code:"

May i Know how to install WMIclient in local machine

Answer (score 0):

The documentation says to either execute

```
cpanm Net::WMIClient
```

or

```
perl -MCPAN -e shell
install Net::WMIClient
```

Did you try that?

Comment: Thanks for reply. may i know where i have to run this command . whether under cpan> or c:> folder. what i have to give input for "Enter the path to the WMI source code:"

Comment: `perl -MCPAN -e shell` will put you in the `cpan>` prompt where you would enter `install Net::WMIClient`.